# Array created with random numbers as index and objects as elements gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have this small script, rolling random numbers and push them into an array. If an item (an object) doesn't exist it must be added, else it needs to be updated. The id's must be an unique identifier. Somehow I get duplicate id's and I am not sure why that happens.

I was hoping to get this after the rolls (30 rolls example):

```
[{"id":1,"min":0,"max":18},{"id":2,"min":0,"max":2},{"id":3,"min":0,"max":10}]
```

instead of:

```
[{"id":1,"min":0,"max":7},{"id":2,"min":0,"max":2},{"id":3,"min":0,"max":10},{"id":1,"min":0,"max":11}]
```

Does anyone know's what the problem might be? Thanks in advance.

```js
var coll_ = [];

for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

  random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

  if (!coll_[random_number]) {

    // Item doesnt exist so will be added to the array
    coll_.push({
      id: random_number,
      min: 0,
      max: 1
    });
  } else {
    // Item exists so it will be updated
    coll_[random_number]['max']++;
  }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(coll_));
```

Comment: You’re not using `random_number` as index when adding new items…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`coll` is an *array* - checking `coll_[random_number]` will only check whether some index exists, which doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the `id`. Instead of using an array, use an object indexed by `id`s, and then get that object's values after you're done iterating:

```js
const obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
  const rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

  if ( !obj[rand] ) {
  // Item doesnt exist so will be added to the array
     obj[rand] = {id: rand, min: 0, max: 1};
     
  } else {
     // Item exists so it will be updated
     obj[rand].max++;
  } 
}

console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Also try to avoid implicitly creating global variables - when using a new variable name, always declare it with `const` (or `let` or `var`) first.

Answer (score 0):

The following code (modified) gives the expected result:

```
var coll_ = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

    // Item doesnt exist so will be added to the array
    if (!coll_[random_number]) {

        coll_[random_number] = {
                                    id: random_number,
                                    min: 0,
                                    max: 1
                                };
    } else {
        // Item exists so it will be updated
        ++coll_[random_number].max;
    }
}

coll_.shift(); // See note below
console.log(coll_.toSource());
document.write(JSON.stringify(coll_));
```

*The Output:*

- Console: `[{id:1, min:0, max:4}, {id:2, min:0, max:1}, {id:3, min:0, max:5}]`
- Browser: `[{"id":1,"min":0,"max":4},{"id":2,"min":0,"max":1},{"id":3,"min":0,"max":5}]`

Note about `coll_.shift();`:

This statement removes the first element of the `coll_` array - which is `coll_[0]` and its value is `undefined`. This happens because the array has elements with indexes 1, 2, and 3. The element at zero index is created by the JS.